# Storage of client project pictures on the server. Best directory layout?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an ajax/php file uploader that works fine.

The file uploader is a php page **posted to**, with the **following parameters** in the url besides the files it is going to process.

```
/beta6/upload/?client_id=111&project_id=222
```

My question is, is the follwing the **most appropriate folder storage structure** for this application?

**A.** My initial though..

```
/beta6/upload/111/222/file1.jpg
/beta6/upload/111/222/file2.jpg
/beta6/upload/111/222/file3.jpg
```

Comment: It depends, I like to store them in a Zipfile, but there may be some performance issues with images.  You also want to be sure to sanitize filenames if users can name the files.  This is pretty opinion based, and it depends a lot on your specific use case.  If users can modify that path at all I would be very careful, what if someone puts 112 in instead of 111, and uploads some porn to another users account. etc.  Generally exposing or using a user ID (that is supplied by the client) is not advisable.

Comment: Unique file names are currently generated. No user interaction required.

Comment: Excellent point on the vulnerability. hmmm...

Comment: even so, by putting the client ID in the url, your exposing it to be modified by an end user.  Better to get it from the session.   I once had a user upload a file with a single quote in it to a linux server, not sure how they put that in there, but it was a pain just to delete the file.  Now I sha1 the filename and time and use that as the filename, then I store the name they give me along with the hash in the DB that way I can display the name they want and dont have to worry about any special characters in the name... :)

Comment: Indeed more secure. I have read somewhere that session variables are not ideal for storage or possibly constantly changing data. For example, the logged in user is a good session variable but the client id that the user id currently working on can change at any point and is best passed around in a different way. Is this relevant in this case?

Comment: Well the problem with data that changes is it can be impossible to find out where or when it was changed, and quickly becomes a nightmare to debug.

Comment: It's no more secure as you can use things like Post Man, to submit arbitrary data to the server.  The only secure way is to get the ID internally and not allow them access to it at all.  You should also be aware of Directory tree transverse attacks, something all to often overlooked.  AKA. the Dot Dot Slash attack.  In any case using the Session for the current users ID is perfectly acceptable, and any user management system worth it's salt will expose this data via the session.

Comment: So much brain food. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a quick article on Wikipedia about Directory Transverse, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack